# Integral convergence and weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Given that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a connected bounded Lipshitz domain and $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. We denote $\Gamma$ as the boundary of the domain. We have the following additional results:

$a(u_{k},\nabla  v) \rightarrow a(u, \nabla v)$ in  $L^{p'}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $b(u_{k}) \rightarrow b(u)$ in $L^{q'}(\Gamma)$, $\nabla (u_{k}-u) \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^{p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $(u_{k}-u)|_{\Gamma} \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^{q}(\Gamma)$.

How does it follow then that:

$\int_{\Omega}a(u_{k},\nabla v)\cdot\nabla(u_{k}-u)dx + \int_{\Gamma}b(u_{k})(u_{k}-u)dS \rightarrow 0$

My idea is that it seems that Holder's Inequality should be used so for the first integral term:

$\int_{\Omega}a(u_{k},\nabla v)\cdot\nabla(u_{k}-u)dx \leq (\int_{\Omega}|a(u_{k},\nabla v)|^{p'})^{\frac{1}{p'}}(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla(u_{k}-u)|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and since $a(u_{k},\nabla v)$ is convergent it is bounded, I am just not sure we can state that $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla(u_{k}-u)^{p}|^{\frac{1}{p}} \rightarrow 0$ simply from the assumption $\nabla (u_{k}-u) \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^{p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

Any ideas of how this would be resolved? I can add information if some important info is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there:

For the first term it is convenient to subtract and add $a(u,\nabla v)\nabla(u_k-u)$, so you get to terms:
$$
A = \int_\Omega (a(u_k,\nabla v) - a(u,\nabla v))\nabla(u_k-u)
$$
and
$$
B = \int_\Omega a(u, \nabla v) \nabla(u_k-u).
$$

$B$ clearly tends to $0$ be the hypothesis of weak convergence. For the $A$ term note that weakly convergent sequences are uniformly bounded in $L^p$ (this is a consequence of the uniform boundedness principle and the duality of $L^p$). So as you said, by Holder's inequality you can estimate $|A|$ by
$$
\|a(u_k,\nabla v)-a(u,\nabla v)\|_{L^{p'}} \|\nabla(u_k-u)\|_{L^{p}},
$$
the first factor tends to $0$ by the strong convergence hypothesis, while the second factor remains uniformly bounded by the above remark.

The second integral is estimated similarly.

The basic argument using the principle of uniform boundedness above goes like this: if $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^p$ then you can define the functionals $\Lambda_n(\psi) = \int f_n \psi$. By weak convergence, for all $\psi \in L^{p'}$ we have $\Lambda_n(\psi) \to 0$, in particular $\sup_n |\Lambda_n(\psi)| < \infty$, so by the uniform boundedness principle we must have $\sup_n \|\Lambda_n\|_{L^{p'} \to \mathbb{C}} < \infty$. Now by duality, $\|\Lambda_n\|_{L^{p'} \to \mathbb{C}} = \|f_n\|_{L^p}$, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you refer me to a good text explaining why weakly convergent sequences are uniformly bounded in $L^{p}$ due to the uniform boundedness principle and duality of $L^{p}$?

Comment: @JohnJack I have updated my answer with a proof of this fact. But this is probably in Brezis' book: http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analysis-Differential-Equations-Universitext/dp/0387709134.

Comment: Okay great, thanks.

Comment: Can you see how using this it would follow that: for any $z \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ we also have $\int_{\Omega}a(u_{k},\nabla v)\cdot \nabla z dx + \int_{\Gamma}b(u_{k})zdS \rightarrow \int_{\omega}a(u,\nabla v)z dx + \int_{\Gamma}b(u)z dS$

Comment: @JohnJack It's the same argument: $\nabla z \in L^p(\Omega)$, so the first term converges by the weak convergence hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't you expect $\int_{\Omega}a(u_{k},\nabla v)\cdot \nabla z \rightarrow \int_{\Omega}a(u,\nabla)\cdot \nabla z$ instead of the above? If you disagree with that, you can just say so and I will figure out how to do it. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: @JohnJack oooh sorry, I misread. I don't know why it would converge to that, there must be some property of $a$ I am missing.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will revise the properties of $a$ again, it might even be a typo.